# SPACEBAR in Dojox EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I'm using a `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid` that has an editable cell. The <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> triggers the  ***edit mode*** (which is an ***ok-ish*** approach, I guess). However, if I trigger the edit mode programatically (via a link in an adjacent cell) or by *double-click* and I start typing some text like *"This value is good"*, as soon as I hit the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> (after *"This"*) the grid tries to trigger the edit again and it deletes what I've entered so far.

Does anybody know how to fix this? It's really annoying because it happens only when using other means of entering the cell in ***edit mode*** other than `onKeyDown` event (i.e. if I focus the cell and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the cell goes into *edit mode* and spaces are allowed; if I *double-click* the cell and enter *edit mode* the first time I press <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> the edit mode messes up).

Thank your for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. But I realized that in my case issue is valid only if singleClickEdit property is set to false. Other words if singleClickEdit:true - it is possible to enter space to the editable field

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was able to solve this issue. this post helps me:
[Dynamically control edit mode of dojo DataGrid column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373135/dynamically-control-edit-mode-of-dojo-datagrid-column)

and here is a final solution:

```
var customOnEditActivate = function(e){
 var event;
 if(this._click.length > 1 && has('ie')){
  event = this._click[1];
 }else if(this._click.length > 1 && this._click[0].rowIndex != this._click[1].rowIndex){
  event = this._click[0];
 }else{
  event = e;
 }
 this.focus.setFocusCell(event.cell, event.rowIndex);
 this.onRowClick(event);
 this.edit.setEditCell(event.cell, event.rowIndex);
 this.onRowDblClick(e);
};

wordsGrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                query : ...,
                store : ...,
                singleClickEdit: false,
                selectionMode:"single",
....
}, container);
dojo.connect(wordsGrid, "onCellDblClick", customOnEditActivate);
```

so the edit event is fired even without connecting to onCellDblClick. But seems that code inside customOnEditActivate does some magic with grid properties and fixes this issue. If anyone has some other solution - please share it!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll give it a try and let you know.