# Dynamically control edit mode of dojo DataGrid column

Tags: datagrid, dojo, grid

I just started using dojo and just started to play around with it. Basically what I want do is that I have a table which has 2 columns A and B. The cells in Column B will either be locked or editable depending on the value of column A.

Is there a way to set the editable property at cell level and not on the column level as defined in the layout?

I tried using the formatter but can't get it to work properly.

Comment: That is quite tough job. I also tried a lot of things and had to follow a different approach for editing cells. You can avoid cell update by capturing onApplyCellEdit but locking the cells for non-editable is not a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the grid function `onCellDblClick` - but this is version-specific code. If the dojo.version changes in your page, the grid Event.js may have other behaviors. The following snippet is taken from **... /dojox/grid/_Event.js** from version *1.7.2*.

If your editing is set to fire via doubleclicking a cell (default behavior), you may choose to simply ignore it with a well placed `return` in the following:

```
    var customOnEditActivate = function(e){
            // summary:
            //              Event fired when a cell is double-clicked.
            // e: Event
            //              Decorated event object contains reference to grid, cell, and rowIndex
            var event;
            if(this._click.length > 1 && has('ie')){
                    event = this._click[1];
            }else if(this._click.length > 1 && this._click[0].rowIndex != this._click[1].rowIndex){
                    event = this._click[0];
            }else{
                    event = e;
            }
////
// entrypoints of interest: event.cell & event.cellNode(.innerHTML)
// As example we could ignore editing mode if cell contains 'NON_EDITABLE'

if(cell.innerHTML.match("NON_EDITABLE"))
     return;

//
////
            this.focus.setFocusCell(event.cell, event.rowIndex);
            this.onRowClick(event);
            this.edit.setEditCell(event.cell, event.rowIndex);
            this.onRowDblClick(e);
    },
```

So whilst initializing your grid, set the config parameter `onCellDblClick` to the above function:

```
require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid"], function(DataGrid) {
  var grid = new DataGrid({
    onCellDblClick: customOnEditActivate
  });
});
```

or

```
<div 
      data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" 
      data-dojo-props="onCellDblClick: customOnEditActivate"
></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try this one out when I get back home.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the

`canEdit: function(inCell, inRowIndex)`

method of the DataGrid.  From that, you can get the item:

`this.getItem(inRowIndex)`

then work out if it should be editable or not, and return true/false.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work (similar to Ed Jellard's suggestion):

```
<script type="dojo/require">
    jsonRestStore : "dojox/data/JsonRestStore",
    contentPane   : "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    dataGrid      : "dojox/grid/DataGrid"
</script>

<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">
  <script type="dojo/method">
      configStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore
        ( { target : "/data/config",
            idAttribute : "propertyName" } );

      configStructure =
          [ {field:'propertyName', name:'Property - Name',
               width:20},
            {field:'value', name:'Value',
               editable:true},
            {field:'guiConfigurable', name:'Property Type'},
            {field:'description', name:'Description'}
          ];
  </script>
</div>

<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
       store="configStore"
       structure=configStructure>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="canSort" args="sortInfo">
        return false;
    </script>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onApplyCellEdit" >
        configStore.save();
    </script>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="canEdit" args="inCell, inRowIndex">
        var gc = this.getItem(inRowIndex).guiConfigurable;
        return gc == 'W' || gc == 'D';
    </script>
    <tbody/>
</table>
```